# Gradient to accommodate different div sizes

Tags: html, css

I have a gradient which I want to start from left top, it's endpoint can be left as is.

Here are my current testing scenario's:

```css
.test-1{
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.test-2{
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.test-3{
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.test-4{
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.gradient{
    /* height: 100%;
    width: 100%; */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(190deg, #FFFFFF 22%, transparent 22.1%), 
      linear-gradient(90deg, #5c9c9b 0%, #8ccdcc 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test-1 gradient"></div>

<div class="test-2 gradient"></div>

<div class="test-3 gradient"></div>

<div class="test-4 gradient"></div>
```

- In `.test-1`, the div is too small, so its gradient is cutting off at the top. In this case, I would want it to end on the top left corner so it doesn't appear as if it's ending abruptly.
- `.test-2` is the same.
- `.test-3` is fine, it's not ending abruptly.
- `.test-4` is also fine, it not in the top left corner, but it's not cut off.

How can I cater this gradient to accommodate different div sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the top gradient to make it a triangular shape:

```css
.test-1{
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: 
    /*                                                   position /width height */
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 49.5%,transparent 50%) top/100%  30%     no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(90deg, #5c9c9b 0%, #8ccdcc 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test-1 gradient"></div>
```

And if you want more space at the top add some padding

```css
.test-1{
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  background: 
      linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 49.5%,transparent 50%) top/100% 30% no-repeat,
      linear-gradient(90deg, #5c9c9b 0%, #8ccdcc 100%) no-repeat;
  background-origin:content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-1 gradient"></div>
```

Or add offset to the gradients:

```css
.test-1{
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: 
      linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 49.5%,transparent 50%)left 0 top 20px/100% 30% no-repeat,
      linear-gradient(90deg, #5c9c9b 0%, #8ccdcc 100%) left 0 top 20px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-1 gradient"></div>
```

Another idea is to consider skew transformation

```css
.test-1{
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
}
.test-1:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:20px; /* Control the space */
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, #5c9c9b 0%, #8ccdcc 100%);
  transform:skewY(8deg);
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-1 gradient"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the gradient can use `vh` instead of `%`

```css
.test-1{
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.test-2{
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.test-3{
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.test-4{
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.gradient{
    /* height: 100%;
    width: 100%; */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
   background: 
       linear-gradient(190deg, #FFFFFF 60vh, transparent 34.1vh), 
       linear-gradient(90deg, #5c9c9b 0, #8ccdcc 100vh);
}
```

```html
<div class="test-1 gradient"></div>

<div class="test-2 gradient"></div>

<div class="test-3 gradient"></div>

<div class="test-4 gradient"></div>
```